# whats the difference with %i and %li?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm asking because i'm getting a "!" caution warning

asking me to replace %i with %li:

```
 else if ([sender tag] == 8)
    {
        SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:6];

        NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
       [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
  }
```

here

```
  NSLog(@"TAG IS: %i", (long)[sender tag]);

}
```

If I change it will it still be ok?

Comment: Read the docs for the format specifiers. `%i` is for `int`. `%l` is for `long`.

Comment: Yes I've read them, but if I change them will it make a difference when a purchase is made? Really whats the difference and why do I have to change it - as suggested by xcode? Do I really have to change it?

Comment: Since you have casted `[sender tag]` to `long` you must use `%l`. They need to match.

Comment: I'd like to add a comment that %i acutally works fine(no warning) when you're running on old ipad-mini but you'll get warning when running on ipad64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%i` prints an `int`, but `%li` prints a `long`.  Since you are printing a `long`, you should change it.

Comment: will it distort my in-app purchases for the user?

Comment: No.  You are telling NSLog that you were giving it an `int`, but you are actually giving it a `long`.  Changing `%i` to `%li` tells it you are giving it a `long`, which you are, so you should change it.

Comment: A `long` is 2x the size of an `int`.  That means it can hold a much larger value, but also takes up more memory.